# how to compare value in one column with other column in datatable C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I want to compare all the values in column B with the values in column A using the < operator, then display the results in a label..

i got this code which counts how many data have value < 0 in column A. and displays the result in label.

```
        int Col_A = Dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<decimal>("Column_A") < 0).Count();
        lbCount.Text = numberOfRecords2.ToString();
```

what i want is "Column_B < Column_A = result".

Thank you :)

Comment: what about this? `x => x.Field<decimal>("Column_B") < x.Field<decimal>("Column_A")` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "display the results"? Are you saying that you want to display the count of the rows where one column is less than the other or do you want to display the actual data in those rows? This makes no actual sense: *"Column_B < Column_A = result"*. The result of the `<` operator is a Boolean value, i.e. `true` or `false`, and I doubt that's what you want to display.

Comment: @viveknuna ah.. its that simple, and it worked.. thanks for the help..

Comment: @jmcilhinney I mean, I want to know how much data in column B has less value than the value in Column A, let's say I have data in the form of values in column B 10 rows and 10 rows in column A, then compare all values in column B with all values in column A with the < operator. if found the results will be displayed on the label, for example there are 2 results in column B whose value is less than the value in Column A.

Comment: So you just want the count, which you already know how to get. You already know how to get a column value and you already know how to compare two values. You already have everything you need. You just need to put the pieces together by applying a little logic. This seems like a question that you really should have been able to answer for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

if you want count of the rows where value of `Column_A` is less than `Column_B` :

```
 Dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => int.Parse(x["Column_A"].ToString()) < int.Parse(x["Column_B"].ToString())).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

@Philipe As discussed in comments you could try `x => x.Field<decimal>("Column_B") < x.Field<decimal>("Column_A")`.

You just need to compare the respective column in place of the hardcoded value `0`

Comment: I have a few more questions, after knowing the results, can they also be displayed in the datagridview ?

Comment: @Philipe didn't get you, can you explain a bit

Comment: the code you provided before displays the result in "2 items" label, then the label has a Click event and when I press the label, Datagridview displays the result. like filtering data in gridview.

Comment: @Philipe that is completely different question, so you should raise a new question and you can share the link here. I will have a look

Comment: ah ok.. I want to filter the data in the datagrid, the filter process must be based on criteria, namely: "all values in column B whose values are less than the values in column A".

Comment: sorry in advance if it's bothersome, I'm not good at English.. the task given by this teacher is a bit troublesome :)